# Overwrite paginator items in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a list of ids that come from a complicated query. I paginate the response of that complicated query and then use those ids to get the eloquent models.  I then put it through a resource with the pagination meta data.

The laravel `AbstractPaginator` class protects the `items` attribute so you cannot easily overwrite them. I have a solution to use a `ReflectionProperty` but I'm after a simpler solution.

The below works but it is not particularly elegant.

```
// $studentIds == Long complicated query that would return 1000s of students
$data = $studentIds->paginate(); // Execute the query limited to 15.

// Use ids to get eloquent models for our students
$students = Student::whereIn('id', $data->pluck('id'))->get();

// Overwrite paginate `items` attribute so that our response contains pagination meta.
$rp = new \ReflectionProperty('Illuminate\Pagination\AbstractPaginator', 'items');
$rp->setAccessible(true);
$rp->setValue($data, $students);

return new StudentResourceCollection($data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `setCollection()` method:

```
$data->setCollection($students);
```